# What event will be fired when I move a edge's target point to another vertex?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

What event will be fired when I move a edge's target point to another vertex? How to get the old target and new target of the edge?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the new target Vertex using `mxEvent.CONNECT` listener
like this:

```
    graph.connectionHandler.addListener(mxEvent.CONNECT, function(sender, evt)
    {
        var edge = evt.getProperty('cell');
        var source = graph.getModel().getTerminal(edge, true);
        var target = graph.getModel().getTerminal(edge, false);
        // target variable contains the newly connected Vertex
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I didn't describe well, the point is that no cells added but change the edge to connect another vertex, which will not fire `mxEvent.CONNECT`. I found it will fire `mxEvent.CELL_CONNECTED`, the property `previous` and `terminal` are the old terminal and new terminal of the edge.